# I have a set of ingredients. And I need to retrieve all the recipes that contain those ingredients in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

For example I have an array of ingredients and I need to get all the recipes that contain those ingredients. I am not sure what to use, HashMap, HashSet or ArrayList. Could anybody show a small example?

Comment: How are you representing the recipes and ingredients?  The answer to your question depends completely on the existing data model.

Comment: I just started the program and I am not sure how to do better. The idea is to have an array of ingredients that a user will input to get all the recipes that contain those ingredients. And I thought that using Arrays is not really good, there will be to many nested loops which will make the program slow. So, my question was how to use HashMap and HashSet in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HashMap the key will be `Ingredient` and the value will be a `HashSet<Recipe>`

So you will have:

```
HashMap<Ingredient , HashSet<Recipe>> map;
```

Each HashSet in the map contains all the Recipes that have the corresponding key Ingredient

Now, given a set of Ingredients as "keys" find their corresponding HashSet's in the map and put them on a Set

The result is a `Set<HashSet<Recipe>>`

Now, to illuminate duplicates iterate over each Recipe in each HashSet in the Set and add the Recipes to another HashSet which is the final result

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find all recipes containing *either one of the given ingredients*, you essentially need a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) mapping every ingredient to a set of all recipes that contain it.

You then return results that showed up in at least one of the searches.

Since Java has no such data structure built in, you can either use a `Map<Ingredient, Set<Recipe>>` or use a multimap implementation from some third-party library (Apache Commons, Google Guava etc.).

---

If you need to find recipes containing *all given ingredients*, that is a bit more complicated with such data structure, and a solution would depend on what tradeoff between performance and space complexity you want to make:

#### 1) Multimap - fast, high memory consumption

You could create all possible subsets of ingredients for each recipe and store the recipe reference for each of the subsets in a `Map<Set<Ingredient>, Set<Recipe>>`. This will have constant lookup time, but the map will be relatively big

#### 2) Multimap - slow, low memory consumption

You could use the `Map<Ingredient, Set<Recipe>>` approach, but instead of returning all results from searches for each ingredient, return only results that are present in all the per-ingredient search results

#### 3) Use a bitmask index

[Bitmask index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) is the data structure that is used in databases for such type of tasks. It represents each ingredient's presence as one bit in the key and is able to perform bit operations on the key when searching for matches (i.e. it is able to search the index using the *has at least these ingredients* manner).

Comment: Might it be Map<Ingredient, Set<Recipe>>

Comment: @MGoksu Indeed, thanks.